# Wildfly Clustering and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, infinispan, wildfly-10

I'm setting up a cluster of wildfly instances to run my application. It's using hibernate for its persistance.

I'm working from the infinispan config from standalone-ha.xml, jgroups I've altered to use tcp ping instead as I cannot use multicast in my environment.

Session replication is working perfectly, my mod_jk load balancer is not using sticky sessions and both of the servers in the cluster (only testing with 2) are serving up pages successfully.

I am experiencing an intermittent issue with hibernate however:

```
2016-08-16 10:14:47,518 INFO  [stdout] (default task-8) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

2016-08-16 10:14:47,518 INFO  [stdout] (default task-8)     at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.openTemporarySessionForLoading(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:274)

2016-08-16 10:14:47,518 INFO  [stdout] (default task-8)     at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:201)

2016-08-16 10:14:47,519 INFO  [stdout] (default task-8)     at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:546)

2016-08-16 10:14:47,519 INFO  [stdout] (default task-8)     at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:133)

2016-08-16 10:14:47,519 INFO  [stdout] (default task-8)     at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:277)
```

I'm using wildfly 10, which is running hibernate 5.

Source of the class in question:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.CR3/org/hibernate/collection/internal/AbstractPersistentCollection.java#AbstractPersistentCollection.openTemporarySessionForLoading%28%29

The class is used for lazy loaded lists (with a one to many relationship), among other things.

Here's some of the code:

```
@Table(name = "[User]")
@Entity
public class User extends CommonDomainBase
{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserSearchingPreference> searchingPreferences;

    public List<UserSearchingPreference> getSearchingPreferences()
    {
        return searchingPreferences;
    }
}
```

From what I can see, the `sessionFactoryUuid` will be serialised when. So if the User is loaded on server 1, replicated to server 2, and a different request which hits server 2 attempts to call `getSearchingPreferences()` the `sessionFactoryUuid` which relates to the hibernate session on server 1 cannot be used to lookup the session on server 2, because it won't exist.

Is anyone able to confirm if I'm correct in my assumption and suggest a solution?

I'm not sure whether this is some hibernate configuration that needs adjusting, or if I should be in some way detaching objects before they are replicated.

Comment: For verifying that given behaviour is a bug, Hibernate Forum https://forum.hibernate.org/ is probably a better place - SO is more of a knowledge-base of solutions.

Comment: @Flavius I wasn't sure if it was a bug, or if I was just doing something wrong. I will post in the hibernate forum as well.

Comment: then cross-link the posts, please.

Comment: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043534&e=0

Comment: See also https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11091 (submitted by Martin Cassidy as a result of the Hibernate forum discussion)